# Microsoft Surface Pro choices for Ubuntu install. Which is better?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, microsoft, surface

I am looking to install Ubuntu on my Surface Pro.  There are two option that others suggest.

- [First](http://www.geek.com/articles/mobile/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-20130211/) is to install Ubuntu as the sole OS and use a restore disk
  every time I want to use windows.
- [Second](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2013/02/how-to-install-virtual-ubuntu-in-surface-pro-windows-8.html) is to use a virtual machine with Hyper-V.

What is the difference of the OS type latency issues for the above options? What would be the best option to achieve maximum speed of either OS? Would a better option exist to achieve a relatively fast switch between OS types without having to  restore windows(eg. could you partition or is Secure boot an issue?).

PS. I should note that my intention is to use Adobe CS Master Suite (most of it), 365 word and excel under windows and obviously don't want to install them every time. Install space is plenty at 96GB free(128GB Surface).

Comment: How about moving this question into a Microsoft forum???

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version of Ubuntu 64-bit for that device and add the wine ppa by typing this command into Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Now you can install Wine1.5 from the Software Centre which will allow you to run Adobe CS and MS Office Suite to save you needing Windows7/8 at all...

To speed up and enable Trim support for your SSD drive check this link:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html

And enjoy your new Surface Pro running Ubuntu 12.10 or above :)